# Pointers to struct and array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

Questions are based on the following code :

```
struct t
{
     int * arr;
};
int main()
{
     struct t *a = malloc(5*sizeof(struct t));
     a[2].arr = malloc(sizeof(int));//line 1
     a[2].arr[1] = 3; //line 2
}
```

1. In line 2 I'm accessing the array `arr` using the `.` (dot) operator and not the `->` operator. Why does this work?
2. When i rewrite line 2 as `(a+2)->arr[1] = 3` this works. But if I write it as `(a+2)->(*(arr+1)) = 3` I get a message as `expected identifier before '(' token`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Hello out-of-bounds access !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For line 1, the dot operator works in this case, because the array access dereferences the pointer for you. `*(a+2) == a[2].` These two are equivalent in both value and type.
2. The "->" operator, expects an identifier after it, specifically the right argument must be a property of the type of the left argument.  Read the messages carefully, it really is just complaining about your use of parentheses.  (Example using the . operator instead: `a[2].(arr)` is invalid, `a[2].arr` is just dandy.)

Also, if we can extrapolate meaning from your code, despite its compilation errors, there is the potential for memory related run time issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. `a[2]` is not a pointer. The indexing operator (`[]`) dereferences the pointer (`a[2]` is equivalent to `*(a+2)`).
2. `(*(arr+1))` is an expression. If you want to do it that way, you want to get the pointer `(a+2)->(arr+1)`, then derefrence it: `*((a+2)->arr+1)`. Of course, since you've only `malloc`ed enough memory for one `int`, this will attempt to access unallocated memory. If you `malloc(sizeof(int)*2)`, it should work.

Comment: Please correct part 2 of your answer. "dereference it `*((a+2)->arr+1)`"

Answer (score 0):

1. `->` dereferences a pointer and accesses its pointee. As you seem to know `a[1]` is equivalent to `*(a + 1)`, where the dereference already takes place.
2. The expression `(a+2)->arr[1]` is equivalent to `*((a+2)->arr + 1)`.
3. You allocated one single `struct t` for `a[2].arr`, then wrote in the second one. Oops.